# Invalid write after allocating memory for struct member in array of structs

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

I need to pass an array of structs to a function and it is my understanding that I have to allocate memory for the whole array of structs, as well as for each individual struct member in every struct inside the array.

The way I have done it results in an invalid write error from valgrind (caused in the second line inside function read_file). What  is wrong?

```
typedef struct test
{
    char *string1; 
    int num1; 
    int num2;
    char *string2;
} Test;

static void read_file(Test *test)
{
    test = (Test *)calloc(16, sizeof(test));
    test[0].string1 = (char *)calloc(strlen("hello") + 1, sizeof(char));
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    Test test[16];

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        memset(&test[i], 0, sizeof(test[i]));
        test[i] = (Test) { "", 0, 0, "" };
    }

    read_file(test);
    return 0;
}
```

PS: I know that I have to free the allocated memory, but first I want to get the above code working.

Comment: Don't forget that arguments are passed by *value*, i.e. they are *copied*. Modifications (i.e. assignments to the local argument variables) of the copies will not change the original. Think about that when you do the assignment to `test` inside the `read_file` function.

Comment: Besides, `test` is already pointing to (the first element of) an existing array, why do you need to allocate new memory?

Comment: Lastly, in C you [should not cast the result of `malloc` (or siblings like `calloc`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Test *test
```

The `test` variable inside `read_file` function is a `pointer` to the Test struct.

```
sizeof(test)
```

This is equal to the sizeof of a *pointer*.

```
test = (Test *)calloc(16, sizeof(test));
```

This allocates memory for 16 *pointer* to `Test` structure. This does not allocate memory for 16 structures, only for pointers to them.

```
test[0].string1 =
```

is invalid and undefined behavior happens. As `sizeof(test)` is way smaller then `sizeof(Test)`, there is not enough memory to access `test0[].string1`. So this accesses the memory "out of bounds" and this accesses invalid / not allocated memory region. As you try to write to it (you are doing an assigment) the expresssion is invalid and undefined behavior happens. Valgrind correctly detects that as "write error" - you try to write to memory you don't own.

Comment: Even after changing sizeof(test) to sizeof(Test) I still get the same error for test[0].string1 = ...

Comment: I figured it out: I'm reading a CSV file (into the array of structs) with 16 lines of data. That's the 16 structs I'm (c)allocating memory for. However, there is also the "header line" in the CSV file (describing the columns), which I totally forgot! Now, after correcting this to test = (Test *)calloc(17, sizeof(Test)); my code works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

The `test` array in `main` already has memory allocated for it.

You then pass it into the `read_file` function, so you do not need to allocate memory for it again. Remove this :

```
test = (Test *)calloc(16, sizeof(test));
```

Btw, you probably intended `sizeof(Test)` (or alternatively `sizeof(*test)`) there. `sizeof(test)` is the same as `sizeof(Test*)`, which is almost certainly smaller than `sizeof(Test)`.

Comment: You can also use `sizeof(*test)` instead of `sizeof(Test)`. (Both are valid)

Comment: Without that line (test = (Test *)calloc(16, sizeof(test));) the program terminates with the error "Aborted (core dumped)". So I guess I do need it?!

Comment: @ci7i2en4 : are you sure you're talking about the code you posted in your question ? Or are you doing more than shown ?

Comment: The snippet in my original posting is part of a much longer code. However, I'm certain that there is no error in parts not shown as I have tested those for weeks without ever encountering any problems. Only since earlier today, after adding what is shown, does the "invalid write" error occur. Or the "Aborted (core dumped)", if I delete the line you mentioned.

Comment: @ci7i2en4 That suggests your other code has [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and that it worked by luck.  Valgrind should show you where your other code is going wrong.

Comment: Even if you are right, Valgrind says the error is in the line test = (Test *)calloc(16, sizeof(Test)); That's why I'm asking here. Without the code snipped I posted, the rest of the code runs perfectly fine and Valgrind doesn't find a single error.

Comment: ^^ edit: I meant this line: test[0].string1 = (char *)calloc(strlen("hello") + 1, sizeof(char));

Comment: And without the following line Valgrind says "*** stack smashing detected ***: program terminated": test = (Test *)calloc(16, sizeof(Test));

Comment: @ci7i2en4 : the code you posted in your question does not correspond with the behavior you describe. Did you try actually running the code from your question (with my fix), and see if you get the problem there ?

Comment: I already figured it out; please see my comment to the answer of Kamil Cuk. Apparently, I do need the line test = (Test *)calloc(17, sizeof(Test));

Comment: @ci7i2en4 : maybe that's the case in your actual code, but that's *not* the case in the code you posted in your question. In future, to get useful help, make sure that your mcve matches your actual problem. Refer to [How do I ask a good question ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details.